# Вставка изображений в HTML

Tags: html, теги, атрибуты

Как сделать изображение со ссылкой на mp3 в той же вкладке

---

при таком записе изображение изчезает,а мне надо чтобы изображение осталос ,а мп3 произносилос как за кадром

---

Audio

Comment: Ссылка на мп3 ничем не отличается от обычной ссылки.

Answer (score 3):

Если я Вас правильно понял, Вам нужно при нажатии на картинку воспроизводить аудио файл?

```js
var audio = new Audio('http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3');

$('img').click(function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="...">
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
  <a href="https://адрес файла mp3"><img src="https://картинка на сылку " alt="...." width="100" height="100"></a>
</div>
```