# Проигрыш mp3 по нажатию на изображение на сайте

Tags: html

Я просто хочу, чтобы пользователь нажал на изображение и услышал музыку. Если он нажимает на другое изображение, текущая музыка должна перестать играть, и должен быть воспроизведен другой звук. При этом изображения на вкладке статичны.
Как можно это реализовать ?

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Советую прочитать комментарии к предыдущему вопросу и сделать выводы.

Comment: Здесь не площадка дармовых решений.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вставка изображений в HTML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931041/%d0%92%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-html)

Comment: У меня почему-то тут не появилось поле для ввода ответа, я только был собрался.

Comment: @Олег поезд ушел - вопрос закрыли

Comment: Жаль, вопрос хороший, но если всё на столько зависит от того, о чём этот пользователь спрашивал раньше...

Answer (score 5):

Исключительно по той причине, что мне захотелось попробовать.

```js
$(".play").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#soundFrame").attr("src", this.href);
});
```

```css
#soundFrame {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" class="play">Test 1</a>
<a href="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" class="play">Test 2</a>
<br/>
<iframe id="soundFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```